# Iteration Burndown chart for a specific user

Tags: rally

I have a request to make an Iteration Burndown chart per user. Currently I am displaying the Iteration Burndown for the project as a whole in a html file that I made. How can I filter the rallydatasource to show only items from a specific user id or an array of user ids? Also, how do I find a specific user id? Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

I was also asked by a manager to provide individual burndown reports on all of the team members. After I gave a lengthy reminder of why it was a bad idea in our Agile environment to focus on personal hours worked, rather than the throughput of the team, I was still asked to produce an individual burndown.

To produce the individual burndown, I modified the "Personal Burndown" from the app catalog by changing the query from:

```
query: "((Iteration.Name = \"" + iterationDropdown.getSelectedName() + "\") AND (Owner = \"__USER_NAME__\"))"
```

To:

```
query: "((Iteration.Name = \"" + iterationDropdown.getSelectedName() + "\") AND  (Owner.DisplayName = \"" + ownerDisplayName + "\"))"
```

With the variable ownerDisplayName = "name" set earlier to the name of the person to show the report for.

After creating the report, it allowed me to again have the discussion about why it was not a good practice to focus on individual "productivity", and rather to focus on the results of the team, and what better metrics to care about might be. - The good news was that after using this individual burndown report for a couple of weeks, it was jettisoned as not being valuable.

Comment: How do you edit the query for the Personal Burndown Chart? I have an option to Edit Settings but it only allows me to change the chart's title.

Comment: There is a link to the source on the page in the Rally App Catalog for the Personal Burndown Chart: https://developer.help.rallydev.com/personal-burndown-chart-app You will have to grab the source (html/js/css), copy it, and paste it into a new Rally "Custom HTML" App (with the modified query).  - I should reiterate again, that a manager or someone else tracking a burndown for an individual, is very "unagile", and is something that should be avoided if it is at all possible, because those sorts metrics are not valuable (and often cause harm to the project &the team) in an agile environment.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a particularly agile way to do things.  Rally's app catalog contains a personal burndown app which allows a user to view their own progress for the current iteration but not monitoring of other users...